# Auto Open Excel 2010 file, save and convert to Excel 2003 format

Tags: excel

I need direct import excel to SQL. 
However, the SQL version I am using only support Excel 2013 while the user excel is a 2010 shared workbook.

I am thinking if it is possible to setup a Excel 2010 and use formula to link the cell value from the 2010 shared workbook and then save to Excel 2003 format.

I want to do the above autmatically. Can Excel Marco do so?

I don't know much on excel marco. How can I do so?

Could someone help me?

Ivan

Comment: `I am thinking if it is possible to setup a Excel 2010 and use formula to link the cell value from the 2010 shared workbook and then save to Excel 2003 format.` I get your point, but you can directly do the conversion from 2010 to 2003 via macro/VBA. I posted an answer which does that but I'm not sure if it suits you since you mentioned you don't know much about macro. If you have questions, then just comment it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes. You can try below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim filename
    Dim wb As Workbook

    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.xlsx")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    If wb Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Please select an Excel File": Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

    wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".xlsx", ".xls"), 56 '~~> xlExcel8
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Above code opens an Excel 2010 file then saves it in *xls* (2003) format and close it. HTH.